# js/reactjs - How do i reconstruct data from a json into a array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

So i'm using Azure Application Insights REST API to get data from my web app to construct it into a graph to be displayed on a dashboard.

The json that comes back is as follows:

```
{
  "value": {
    "start": "2017-08-07T23:01:50.847Z",
    "end": "2017-08-08T11:01:50.847Z",
    "interval": "PT1H",
    "segments": [
      {
        "start": "2017-08-07T23:01:50.847Z",
        "end": "2017-08-08T00:00:00.000Z",
        "requests/count": {
          "sum": 317
        }
      },
      {
        "start": "2017-08-08T00:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2017-08-08T01:00:00.000Z",
        "requests/count": {
          "sum": 332
        }
      },
      {
        "start": "2017-08-08T01:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2017-08-08T02:00:00.000Z",
        "requests/count": {
          "sum": 337
        }
      },
      {
        "start": "2017-08-08T02:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2017-08-08T03:00:00.000Z",
        "requests/count": {
          "sum": 326
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to get the **"end"** and **"sum"** values in **"segments"** to construct an array like so since the graph api requires the array to be in this format:

```
[
    ["2017-08-08T00:00:00.000Z", 317], 
    ["2017-08-08T01:00:00.000Z", 332],
    ["2017-08-08T02:00:00.000Z", 337],
    ["2017-08-08T03:00:00.000Z", 326]
```

]

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myArray = resultFromAPI.value.segments.map(function(segment) {
  return [segment.end, segment["requests/count"].sum];
});
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer some **modern JavaScript**, you can also do something like :

```
// “res” is your API response
const newArray = res.value.segments.reduce((acc, val) => {
  return [...acc, [val.end, val['requests/count'].sum]];
}, []);
```

Learn more about [reduce magic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

I hope it will help !

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Something like:

`t.value.segments.map(function(x) { return [ x.start, x['requests/count'].sum] })`